# How to make it so html link tags can work without <a> tags

Tags: javascript, html, pug

So, I'm trying to make it so html link tags can work with  tags.

Normally i would do:

```
<a href="google.ca"> google </a>
```

How would i do it if I want to accomplish:

```
[<link> <label>]
```

so when I input, I will do

```
[google.ca google]
```

to get the same result as a  tags?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is some kind of template language like markdown. Markdown's syntax for a link is

```
[google](http://www.google.ca)
```

Then your server can process the template to produce proper HTML. This could also be done in a build step if you have an application.

There are libraries in many different languages that you could use to achieve this. Here are some:

PHP: https://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/

NodeJS: https://github.com/chjj/marked

Java: https://github.com/sirthias/pegdown

Answer (score 0):

```html
<label onclick="window.location.href='http://www.google.ca'" style="cursor:pointer">google.ca</label>
```

and you mush have javascript enable

Answer (score 0):

Jade is not Markdown.

To do what you want, you'd have to use real HTML/Jade syntax, which means something like this:

```
p Lorem ipsum #[a(href='https://google.ca') Google]
```

or standalone:

```
a(href='https://google.ca') Google
```